# Evaluate $\frac{3}{4}$ to the power of $-3$

Tags: fractions

I have gotten to the next stage where you write it as $\frac{1}{\left(\frac 34\right)}$ to the power of $3$, now I am stuck

I've got it now, thanks everyone.

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}$$

Comment: You should use the relation $\frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{b}{a}$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: $(4/3)^3=\frac{4*4*4}{3*3*3}$

Comment: @rooroo, I made a small edit that might help with your confusion

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
$$\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{-n} = \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^n = \frac{a^n}{b^n}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-3}=\left(\frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}\right)^3=\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3=\frac{4^3}{3^3}=\frac{64}{27}\approx2.37$$

Answer (score 0):

it is $(\frac{4}{3})^3=\frac{4^3}{3^3}=\frac{64}{27}$

Comment: So just to clarify, I need to swap the 3 and 4 over?

Comment: yes  this is right

Comment: and not make it 1 over anything?

Comment: it is $$\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{-3}=\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^3$$